# "An attempt to attach an auto-named database" error

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio

I am making a desktop application in C#, Visual Studio 2010 on Windows XP SP2 Professional.

If I run that application directly from the published folder without running setup OR run it from debug folder OR simply debug the application, it does not give this error. But if I run setup from published folder and then run it from start menu, it gives this error:

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Documents and Settings\Desi\Local Settings\Apps\2.0\Data\K9KMBYK5.881\EKOOHKP2.0Y1\smas..tion_ddac366ea7cca062_0001.0000_c8a0800c5798ef15\Data\SmasDb.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

I am publishing application to a folder in 'my documents'.

> C:\Documents and Settings\Desi\Local Settings\Apps\2.0\Data\K9KMBYK5.881\EKOOHKP2.0Y1\smas..tion_ddac366ea7cca062_0001.0000_c8a0800c5798ef15\Data\1.0.0.0 (this *Data* directory has only the user.config file.)
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\Desi\Local Settings\Apps\2.0\LWGCKB30.QZJ\E81QYJON.ZX9\manifests (contains smas..tion_ddac366ea7cca062_0001.0000_none_a42d8ca7a940cae4.cdf-ms smas..tion_ddac366ea7cca062_0001.0000_none_a42d8ca7a940cae4.manifest smas.exe_ddac366ea7cca062_0001.0000_none_3d144d2ce016963b.cdf-ms smas.exe_ddac366ea7cca062_0001.0000_none_3d144d2ce016963b.manifest)
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\Desi\Local Settings\Apps\2.0\LWGCKB30.QZJ\E81QYJON.ZX9\smas.exe_ddac366ea7cca062_0001.0000_none_3d144d2ce016963b (contains 
>   SMAS.exe.config, SmasDb.mdf, SmasDb_log.ldf)
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\Desi\Local Settings\Apps\2.0\LWGCKB30.QZJ\E81QYJON.ZX9\smas..tion_ddac366ea7cca062_0001.0000_c8a0800c5798ef15 (this directory has all files including all dlls, SmasDb.mdf and SmasDb_log.ldf, SMAS.exe.config, some .cdf-ms and .manifest files NOT same as above .cdf-ms and .manifest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you verify that the long path (C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Local Settings\Apps\2.0\Data\MP63M1NA.ZG5\BCOVJJWN.C53\smas..tion_ddac366ea7cca062_0001.0000_9c79a710d42895b6\Data\SmasDb.mdf) to see if there actually is a database there?

From the three options in the error message, I would go for: *or specified file cannot be opened*

You'll have to think about where you want the database to be (on a non-developer computer), and make sure it is copied there.

See the post *[Working with Databases in Visual Web Developer 2005 Express Edition](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/data/vwd.aspx)* about the |DataDirectory| syntax.

Comment: This is the problem. Above directory only contains the user.config file. All other files are in other directories. Added more details to question.

Comment: How to make sure that databse is copied to datadirectory?

Comment: I made a really bad design i think. The connectionString, DataSet, and all the classes are in another dll project in the same solution. (i did this because the requirement was to make have a dll instead of doing everything in main project) Now the possible solution is to make sure that the database files are copied to DataDirectory. How to do that?

Comment: You can change where |DataDir| points to, see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/dc31ea59-5718-49b6-9f1f-7039da425296/

Comment: The file is not being copied to DataDirectory. How to copy?

Comment: Hurrah!!!!! ClickOnce setup is now working. I added the code to copy smasdb.mdf manually near the installation folder (near |DataDirectory|). App is working fine from start menu without error

Answer (score 0):

You are using ClickOnce and using a SQL CE database? 
Did you include the database in the Published application?

Comment: Yes, i am using ClickOnce and SQL database. And the database is included in published application